# Hide a .gif if it is beside another .gif

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a service where people can upload their images, and I display them on my website. I want to automatically hide a `.gif` if it is uploaded beside another `.gif`.

I don't want this to effect images ending in `.png` or `.jpg`.. only `.gifs`.

Here is an image example..

[image]

If there are three `.gifs` in a row, only display the first one.

I have tried selecting it, and hiding it, but this doesn't work at all.

```
img > .gif{
    display:none;
}
```

Do I need to use JavaScript or jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: What if there are three or more gifs in a row, should only one be visible?

Comment: Yes. You can see my image if there are 3 in a row, only show the first one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this using **pure CSS** - no Javascript/jQuery needed!

Use a combination of the [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the [**direct adjacent combinator**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#adjacent-d-combinators): `+`<sup>1</sup>

This will set `display:none;` on any `gifs` immediately following a `.gif`. Therefore no more than two `.gifs` will ever appear beside each other.

```
img[src$=".gif"] + img[src$=".gif"] { 
    display:none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo here!**](http://jsfiddle.net/hH6ru/)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Usage of the attribute selector and direct adjacent combinator are [**not fully supported**](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2) by IE8 and down.</sub>

Comment: Good use of "attribute ends with" selector, but won't this hide all but the first gif? I think OP needs to clarify.

Comment: It was according to the provided image.

Comment: @WesleyMurch thanks for your help. 3 in a row should only display the last one

Comment: +1 for the, er, hypnotic generated avatar. Note that you cannot write a dynamic selector that would pick an element with that attribute value following another element with the same attribute value - if you need to apply this to all image format you would need to repeat the selector for each format.

Answer (score 10):

Just write:

```
.gif + .gif {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: right - it would definitely work then, however that would require an unneeded class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use @Tomzan 's answer for CSS Selector: Element + Element (I cannot comment because of low reputation) [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp]:

```
.gif + .gif { display: none; }
```

OR without a custom class @ yours CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp):

```
img[src*=".gif"] + img[src*=".gif"] {display: none}
```

From W3c for all CSS selectors of this answer:

> Note: For element+element to work in IE8 and earlier, a < !DOCTYPE>
>   must be declared.

**UPDATE**
The first, using CSS classes would work for IE7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358818(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, just now I could see yours anwers: it's very close with mine. I can delete my post and you could add the W3 references what do you think? (I cannot comment because of reputation, bleh :P)

Comment: Also, there are 2 options for accomplish that: using classes or using attributes. CSS classes would work on old browsers (IE7) as well

Comment: The adjacent selector works @ IE7, but [attribute$="value"] doesn't work. Anyway, sorry for that @JoshC, I'll be more careful next time.